# Why does this page fail to add numbers and redirect?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

So basically I have another page sending information to this page via GET. I have double checked the URL to make sure the GET is working properly, which it is. What I don't understand is why this script won't :

1) Add one to the NumberOfResponse in the admin table...

2) Redirect to the page (see the bottom of the code)

Now the status of the call updates to 2, but nothing else happens, or are there any echos.

Code

```
<?php
session_start();

include '../includes/connection.php';
include 'functions.php';
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$id = escape($_GET['id']);
$banner = escape($_GET['bannerID']);
$bannerName = escape($_GET['bannerN']);

$query = $handler->prepare("UPDATE Calls SET Status = '2', TakenBy = :bannerName WHERE ID=:id");
$query->bindParam(':bannerName', $bannerName);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();

$update = $handler->prepare("UPDATE Admins SET NumOfResponse + 1 WHERE ID = :banner");
$update->bindParam(':banner', $banner);
$update->execute();

header("Location: ../pages/incomingCalls.php");
```

Comment: instead of getting the num of respones from the database and add one to it you can just simple do that with mysql 
"UPDATE Admins SET `NumOfResponse`+1 WHERE ID=:banner" it doesn't solve your problem but i though it would help

Comment: So, you're accessing another *page* that is making a request to this page? Also +1 @Ahmadghoneim's comment.

Comment: This is it's own script. I use the GET method to send data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to select the NumOfResponse to update it's value in a second query. You can achieve this by doing a single update query.

Also you are doing something weird here :

```
$query = $query->fetchObject();
```

You don't need to fetch the result of your update query.

Another mistake is when you do :

```
$number = $query->NumOfResponse;
```

You are actually overiding your already incremented value $number with another value.

You can simplify your code like that :

```
<?php
session_start();

include '../includes/connection.php';
include 'functions.php';

$id = escape($_GET['id']);
$banner = escape($_GET['bannerID']);
$bannerName = escape($_GET['bannerN']);

$query = $handler->prepare("UPDATE Calls SET Status = '2', TakenBy = :bannerName WHERE ID=:id");
$query->bindParam(':bannerName', $bannerName);
$query->bindParam(':id', $id);
$query->execute();

$update = $handler->prepare("UPDATE Admins SET NumOfResponse = NumOfResponse  + 1 WHERE ID = :banner");
$update->bindParam(':newNum', $newNum);
$update->bindParam(':banner', $banner);
$update->execute();

header("Location: ../pages/incomingCalls.php");
```

Comment: The page is still not being re-directed back to pages/incomingCalls.php

Comment: Nor does it add one to the number of responses.

Comment: Error
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '+ 1 WHERE ID = ?' at line 1 in /home/wattlema/public_html/scripts/takeCall.php:18 Stack trace: #0 /home/wattlema/public_html/scripts/takeCall.php(18): PDO->prepare('UPDATE Admins S...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/wattlema/public_html/scripts/takeCall.php on line 18

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing echos before the header instruction.
You have to add header values first before printing any content. Remove the echos or use a logging framework such as log4php.

Comment: I update the code in the main post... still nothing.